# Displaying a message when item not found in search input - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript and working on creating basic applications. I am trying to get my "not found" message to display if there is no contact found with a matching name entered in the search input by the user. The app loops through my contacts array but will sometimes still display the "no contact found" message. I understand that this is due to my conditional statement's "else" statement when it loops through an object in the array and the user input does not match that particular object it is currently on. The "not found" message ends up always displaying by default because other object's "names" property in the array will not match the user search input as it loops through the objects.

What I want to know is, how do I get the message to display ***only*** ***after*** it has looped through all of the object's names in my contact array ***and did not*** find any matches? I feel like I'm missing something simple. Is there a value I can return if the loop finds no matches in order to then display the message if that value returns?

Bonus question: Also, how do I get the contact information to display a name if at least a few characters match the user search input? Ex: User enters in "Dav" and one of my contact's names is "David Smith".

If I need to be more clear, please let me know!

Here is my HTML and JS for the app...

HTML:

```
<body>

  <header>Address Book</header>

  <div id="searchButton">
  <input name="searchInput" type=text id="searchInput"><button id="button">Search</button>
  </div>

  <h2 id="notFound"></h2>

  <ul id="contactInfo">
    <li>Name:<span id="contactName"></span></li>
    <li>Phone:<span id="contactNumber"></span></li>
    <li>E-mail:<span id="contactEmail"></span></li>
  </ul>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

The portion of my JavaScript that I'm focused on in this question:

```
//Displays #notFound
    function notFound() {
      var notFound = document.getElementById("notFound");
      notFound.innerHTML = "Person not found in Address Book";
    }

AddressBook.prototype.searchContains = function() {
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
    //if name is in address book
    if (searchInput === this.contacts[i].name) {
      this.contacts[i].listHTML();
      break;
    } else {
      notFound();
    }    
  }
};
```

Here is all of the JavaScript for reference, if needed:

```
//contact object
function Contact (name, number, email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
  this.email = email;
}


//Display's contact information in list spans
Contact.prototype.listHTML = function() {
  var contactName = document.getElementById("contactName");
  var contactNumber = document.getElementById("contactNumber");
  var contactEmail = document.getElementById("contactEmail");
  contactName.innerHTML = this.name;
  contactNumber.innerHTML = this.number;
  contactEmail.innerHTML = this.email;
};

//Displays #notFound
function notFound() {
  var notFound = document.getElementById("notFound");
  notFound.innerHTML = "Person not found in Address Book";
}

//address book object
function AddressBook() {
  this.contacts = [];
}

//add contact function 
AddressBook.prototype.add = function(contact) {
  this.contacts.push(contact);
};

//fucntion to check to see if address book object contains user search
AddressBook.prototype.searchContains = function() {
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
    //if name is in address book
    if (searchInput === this.contacts[i].name) {
      this.contacts[i].listHTML();
      break;
    } else {
      notFound();
    }    
  }
};

//contacts
var roman = new Contact("Roman Kozak", "412-812-1216", "romankozakjr@gmail.com");
var lauren = new Contact("Lauren Kozak", "724-544-5376", "kozaklauren@gmail.com");

//creation of Address Book object
var addressBook = new AddressBook();

addressBook.add(roman);
addressBook.add(lauren);

//When name entered in search box input and search button is clicked
var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  addressBook.searchContains();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change searchContains function for this one:

```
AddressBook.prototype.searchContains = function() {
  // Erases the not found message of a previous search attempt
  // (you could move this to a function if you'd like to)
  var notFound = document.getElementById("notFound");
  notFound.innerHTML = "";

  var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
    //if name is in address book, list and then exit the search function
    if (searchInput === this.contacts[i].name) {
      this.contacts[i].listHTML();
      return;
    }    
  }
  // If the execution reaches this point, it means that the search value
  // hasn't been found
  notFound();
};
```

As for the bonus question you could try using the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function, replacing the condition in the `if` statement with something like this

```
this.contacts[i].name.indexOf(searchInput) != -1
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the only problem is that the "Not found" message stays on the the screen when I do more searches. It doesn't go away when I do a new search. What would be the best way to remove that?

Comment: Check the edit please. I've added two lines that will set the container of the not found message to an empty string each time the function is executed.

Comment: Great! Thank you again. For some reason, when I put the lines in the function like you did, it did not work. It seemed to have kept the not found message blank when I did another search.  I separated it out and created its own function (named eraseNotFound()) and then added eraseNotFound() to the body of the button.addEventListener click function. So when I click the search button, it executes the code you gave me first and then the searchContains().

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate it!!